# Select from self (own) table

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my query: `select uni_num from comes where (select uni_num limit 0,1) like 'a%'`

I know this query doesn't work because there isn't "from" statement, but I want to use limit without from comes.

INSQL isn't there anything query like this? `select * from this.table ~~`

Comment: AFAIK I know there isn't something like that because what would *this* reference to when you have joined to multiple tables in your initial *from* clause?

Comment: you just need to reverse your terms and use a subselect... where 'a%' like (select uni_num from comes);

Comment: There's a lot of solutions, but the gist is that right now you're selecting from _literally nothing_. A subquery is its own special little scope, and you can return a value from it (for instance, the values you want to use, which could be used in your top-level `FROM`).

Comment: That said an explanation would be warranted here: are you trying to filter off a specific value in your table? A subquery nor join is needed for what you have right now, but for what you're trying to do I would probably use a self-join.